# Solr query performance when fetching id and score fields only

Tags: solr, solrj

I am querying a Solr index with 20 million documents. I care about the id and score fields only (`fl=id,score`). The "elapsed time" is usually double that of "QTime". The query is running on the same machine as the index, and the index itself is not distributed.

Is there anything I can do to achieve an elapsed time close to QTime, given the fields I am requesting? Is there documentation of what exactly happens in between, or an easy way to trace it.

Querying is done through Solrj, and I use cursors for pagination/fetching a large number of results. The query parameters are as follows for an example query:

```
q=text:married
fl=id,score
sort=score desc, id desc
cursorMark=*
rows=1000
```

Subsequent calls only have a different value for `cursorMark`.

Comment: What kind of a query you run on that index?

Comment: A single-term query for now.

Comment: any example? i just want to know, where you have problems with perfomance? Could you list one query you use with all params?

Comment: I updated the question with an example.